# Force repost after browser goes offline during original post

Tags: forms, safari

With a simple ordinary HTML form, if you load the page, fill in the form, but then your device goes offline before you hit submit, of course you get the offline error when you submit.

```
<form method=post action=formposted>
  <input name=myname>
  <button type=submit>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then you get back online.

From my testing it seems that in desktop browsers except Safari, if you hit reload from the error page, it re-posts the form values and you get the result you were originally expecting. In Safari on Mac, and it seems on all browsers on iPhone, the reload button actually tries a GET on the URL, which of course doesn't re-post the values.

Is this some Safari/Apple-specific thing, and is there a way around it? I'm  working on a web app where devices may move in and out of service, and I'm hoping to not lose form values whenever possible.